# Кнопка в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть такой код **фрагмента**:

```
 
public class ImportFragment extends Fragment {
```

`private TextView mTimer;
public Button mButton;
Button btn1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_import,container,false);
    return rootView;
}public void onClick (View view ){
    mButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    mTimer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(500000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mTimer.setText("Осталось"+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    mTimer.setText("");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });`

Как сделать кнопку в фрагменте, если там не работает findViewById?

Comment: Добавть код метода OnCreateView.

Comment: Пока что видно только обработчик клика, никаких фрагментов не видно

Comment: Понял, спасибо! По совету @researcher получилось.

Comment: @georgehardcore обработчика тут кстати тоже не видно, видно только метод ```onClick``` который "сам по себе". Т.е. фрагмент не реализует интерфейс ```OnClickListener```, соответственно никто про этот метод не узнает.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    Button mButton;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headline_view, container, false);
        mButton = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //some staff here
            }
        });
        return inflatedView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Если нужные `view` находятся во `view` по которой кликнули, то стоит лишь добавить данную вьюшку перед `findViewById`:

```
public void onClick (View view ){
        mButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        mTimer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        ...
});
```

Если же нет, то вариант предложенный @researcher.

**UPD**:

Вангую что используется `onClick` в разметке, в таком случае над реализовывать данный метод в `Activity`, а не в фрагменте.

Comment: Делал так, приложение вылетало.

Comment: @ЛевНауменко см. `UPD`

Comment: И как быть теперь?

Comment: @ЛевНауменко ну так верно предположил? или у Вас `implements View.OnClickListener`?

Comment: Посмотрите. Я обновил код, всё полностью написал из фрагмента.

Comment: @ЛевНауменко ну получается что в разметке прописан атрибут `onClick`?

Comment: Простите, что вы имеете в виду? 
android:onClick="onClick" - это?

Comment: А что дальше делать? Где должен находиться onClick?

Comment: @ЛевНауменко я же написал, что он может находится только в активити, следовательно надо толи пробрасывать вызов либо пойти путом, что указал `researcher`

Answer (score 0):

Может и не актуально, но может кому пригодится. Метод OnClickListener во фрейме
достаточно в любом Override подставить контекст вызываемой активити.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull final LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_select_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ActionSelectViewModel.class);
    imageView = (ImageView )  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Game.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```